# Connection by ODBC

Tags: openshift

I'm trying connect to my Oracle database in Windows by ODBC to upload data in MySQL database of openshift cloud service. I cannot connect with MySQL database by Tcp/Ip.

How I can connect to MySQL from Oracle pl/sql?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to connect directly to your OpenShift MySQL database, you will need to use the rhc port-forward command to create a connection from your local computer to your gear so that you can access MySQL directly.